# SSRS Bar Chart - X Axis

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a bar chart that represents Interaction Type volume, but I'm having issues removing/renaming the "Series 1" in the X-Axis.  I check the chart configuration set-up for the bar chart, but I'm not able to find a way to remove/rename it? What does the "Series 1" represent?

[image: Bar Chart Call Volume by Interaction Type]
[image: Chart Data set-up]

Comment: Are there some NULL Interaction Type values for some Months?

Comment: Yes. I have interaction type where the value is NULL.

Comment: I believe those are the source of the Series1. Have you tried filtering them out of the dataset (or at least the chart)?

Comment: I figured it out ! because I have a NULL value in my query, but once I converted it with a desired value the series # went away. Thanks. @Hannover Fist